# Использование UWP контролов в WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, uwp, windows-10

Есть ли возможность использовать UWP контролы в WPF приложении?

Comment: Вы и имеете в виду системные (эти нельзя), или написанные вами лично (эти часто можно перенести)?

Comment: @VladD, имел в виду системные, а конкретно хотел использовать MediaElement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет. WPF и UWP — это абсолютно разные несовместимые платформы. У них даже разный рантайм.

Впрочем, мне сложно представить ситуацию, когда может понадобиться контрол UWP в приложении WPF. Обычно в WPF более полноценные контролы, которые лучше подходят для работы с десктопом. Если вам нужен "метрошный" дизайн, то в Сети достаточно наборов стилей, имитирующих плоскоту, в том числе бесплатных.

Что касается MediaElement, то в WPF он тоже есть.

Answer (score 0):

На сегодняшний день это стало возможным используя Xaml Islands https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]